# Add elements in a certain area of an xml

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I had this question answered before but I changed the form of my xml code to be a little better. I am new at this but I have a question: the following is written in run time. I can add all that is needed but if I want to add elements BEFORE PPE/ppe/UID "A3" I am lost. The following is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project>
  <Details>
    <details>
      ///....more specific data
    </details>
  </Details>
  <Tools />
  <Materials />
  <PPE>
    <ppe>
      <UID>A1</UID>
      <ppe1Bool>true</ppe1Bool>
      <ppe1>Test A1</ppe1>
      <ppe2Bool>true</ppe2Bool>
      <ppe2>....</ppe2>
    </ppe>
    <ppe>
      <UID>A3</UID>
      <ppe1Bool>true</ppe1Bool>
      <ppe1>Test A3</ppe1>
      <ppe2Bool>true</ppe2Bool>
      <ppe2>....</ppe2>
    </ppe>
  </PPE>
  <Video />
  <Links />
</Project>
```

This is what I need to add and it needs to be before A3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project>
  <Details>
    <details>
      ///....more specific data
    </details>
  </Details>
  <Tools />
  <Materials />
  <PPE>
    <ppe>
      <UID>A1</UID>
      <ppe1Bool>true</ppe1Bool>
      <ppe1>Test A1</ppe1>
      <ppe2Bool>true</ppe2Bool>
      <ppe2>....</ppe2>
    </ppe>
    //////////////////////////////
    <ppe>
      <UID>A2</UID>
      <ppe1Bool>true</ppe1Bool>
      <ppe1>New</ppe1>
      <ppe2Bool>true</ppe2Bool>
      <ppe2>....</ppe2>
    </ppe>
    /////////////////////////////
    <ppe>
      <UID>A3</UID>
      <ppe1Bool>true</ppe1Bool>
      <ppe1>Test A3</ppe1>
      <ppe2Bool>true</ppe2Bool>
      <ppe2>....</ppe2>
    </ppe>
  </PPE>
  <Video />
  <Links />
</Project>
```

Here's my code and I am close but not quite:

```
     public static void insertRBRowPPE(string strSelection, string strFileName)
     {
        System.Guid desiredGuid = System.Guid.NewGuid(); //I changed this line to A1..A2..A3 for
                                                         //clarity
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(strFileName);
        XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Project/PPE/ppe");
        try
        {
            XElement doc = XElement.Load(strFileName);
            foreach (XElement elm in doc.Elements("PPE"))
            {
                if (node["UID"].InnerText == strSelection)
                {
                    elm.AddBeforeSelf(new XElement("ppe", new XElement("UID", desiredGuid),
                        new XElement("ppe1Bool", ""), new XElement("ppe1", "New"), new XElement("ppe2Bool", ""),
                        new XElement("ppe2", "")));
                }
            }
            doc.Save(strFileName);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

So.. the bugged result is this:

```
   ///xml code etc...
  <Materials />
  <ppe>////////////////////here but I dont want it here
    <UID>A2</UID>
    <ppe1Bool>true</ppe1Bool>
    <ppe1>New</ppe1>
    <ppe2Bool>true</ppe2Bool>
    <ppe2>....</ppe2>
  </ppe>//////////////////////////////
  <PPE>
    <ppe>
      <UID>A1</UID>
      <ppe1Bool>true</ppe1Bool>
      <ppe1>Test A1</ppe1>
      <ppe2Bool>true</ppe2Bool>
      <ppe2>....</ppe2>
    </ppe>
    //////////////////////////////
    I want it here....
    /////////////////////////////
    <ppe>
      <UID>A3</UID>
      <ppe1Bool>true</ppe1Bool>
      <ppe1>Test A3</ppe1>
      <ppe2Bool>true</ppe2Bool>
      <ppe2>....</ppe2>
    </ppe>
  </PPE>
  <Video />
  /// xml code etc....
```

Any help with all the talent thats out there?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting the answer to you previous question:

```
public static void insertRowBeforRowPPE(string strSelection, string strFileName)
{

  XElement doc=XElement.Load(strFileName);
  XElement project = doc.Element("Project");
  XElement ppe = project.Element("PPE");
  foreach(XElement elm in ppe.Elements("ppe")
  {
    if(elm.Element("UID").Value==strSelection)
      elm.AddBeforeSelf(new XElement("PPE",new XElement("UID","a2")));
      //adds PPE node having UID element with value a2 just before the required node
  }
  doc.Save(strFileName);
}
```

Note that you might want to add some more checks - this code would crash if the XML does not contain the `Project` element for example.

Comment: Thanks, My man! your code helped! and it was simple... now that I see it! I did change one thing:                                                                   //XElement project = doc.Element("Project"); //took this line out
      XElement ppe = doc.Element("PPE");
      foreach(XElement elm in ppe.Elements("ppe"))

Comment: @DarkWing If MiMo's answer worked, you should accept it, that way it will give it closure.

Answer (score 0):

MiMo, thanks! Simple once I see it! I commented out one line from your update and it is good.
Thanks again!

```
             //Those who may be interested
            //XElement project = doc.Element("Project");
            XElement ppe = doc.Element("PPE");
            foreach(XElement elm in ppe.Elements("ppe"))
            {
                if (elm.Element("UID").Value == strSelection)
```